# What is the difference between VB and VB.NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, programming-languages, vb6

What is the difference between VB and VB.NET?

Explanation with examples is preferred.

Comment: There is basically zero similarity between the two.

Comment: There is plenty of similarity!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you're making a choice for a new project then the pertinent points are:

- VB6 is legacy (released 1998, the IDE is no longer supported, and the runtime only supported for the lifetime of Win8)
- VS2008 doesn't support VB6
- VB.NET is a modern language, supported in VS2008

I'd say there are very few reasons (if any!) to choose VB.OLD over VB.NET.

If you're "just interested" then the Wikipedia article on each language is quite informative, but in a nutshell they are quite different languages that have superficially similar syntax.  VB had its own runtime, where VB.NET is one of many languages that use the more modern .NET Framework.

Comment: I have to correct one detail. The VB6 runtime [is still supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/ms788708), but the IDE isn't. I still agree that it's almost always better to choose VB.Net for new projects.

Comment: Good point :-)  Will correct!

Comment: I'm sure there must be one somewhere, but I'm still really struggling to come up with a reason to develop VB6 on an unsupported IDE for any new project.

Comment: The runtime is supported for **at least** the lifetime of Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008, not **only**. Microsoft haven't stated yet whether or not it will be supported beyond that. They [say](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/ms788708) they have "no plans" to support it. IMHO These words are carefully chosen to be as scary as possible, without actually definitely saying that they won't support it.

Comment: I was right in my previous comment! Now the runtime is supported for **at least** the lifetime of Windows 8, not **only**. They say they have "no plans" to support it, using deliberately scary words. Just like they did for Windows 8: lo and behold, when Windows 8 was released the VB6 runtime was included and supported.

Comment: Very true, but I'm not sure the runtime is the point: if you're making a new product you'd be crazy to choose a 15-year-old unsupported development environment. I wonder if the VB6 IDE even works in Windows 8... (No plans to check though!)

Answer (score 37):

There are a lot of differences.

- The greatest change in VB6 and VB.NET is of runtime environment. VB6 used the VB-Runtime while VB.NET uses the .Net Common Language Runtime (.Net CLR). The CLR is much better designed and implemented than VB-Runtime. The CLR uses better code translation through Just in Time compiler while VB-Runtime interprets the code. The CLR Garbage Collector is also more efficient than VB6 one as it may detect cyclic references too.
- VB6 was interpreter based language while VB.NET is a compiled language
- VB6 was not a type-safe language while VB.NET is a type safe language. There is no variant type in VB.NET and no magical type conversions happen in VB.NET

some other differences:

### Inheritance

VB.Net supports inheritance by allowing you to define classes that serve as the basis for derived classes. Derived classes inherit and can extend on the properties and methods of the base class. They can also override inherited methods with new implementations of the base class. All classes created with VB.Net are inheritable by default. Because the forms you design are really classes, you can use inheritance to define new forms based on existing ones. For details, see [Inheritance in Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5x4yd9d5%28VS.80%29.aspx).

### Exception Handling

VB.Net supports structured exception handling, using an enhanced version of the Try...Catch...Finally syntax supported by other languages such as C++. Structured exception handling combines a modern control structure (similar to Select Case or While) with exceptions, protected blocks of code, and filters. Structured exception handling makes it easy to create and maintain programs with robust, comprehensive error handlers. For details, see [Introduction to Exception Handling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c68xfk56%28VS.80%29.aspx).

### Overloading

Overloading is the ability to define properties, methods, procedures, or operators that have the same name but use different data types. You can use overloaded procedures to provide as many implementations as necessary to handle different kinds of data, while giving the appearance of a single, versatile procedure. For details, see [Overloaded Properties and Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1z71zbeh.aspx).

### Overriding Properties and Methods

The Overrides keyword allows derived objects to override characteristics inherited from parent objects. Overridden members have the same arguments as the members inherited from the base class, but they have different implementations. A member's new implementation can call the original implementation in the parent class by preceding the member name with MyBase. For details, see [Overriding Properties and Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/818x9db9%28VS.90%29.aspx).

### Constructors and Destructors

Constructors are procedures that control initialization of new instances of a class. Conversely, destructors are methods that free system resources when a class leaves scope or is set to Nothing. VB.Net supports constructors and destructors using the Sub New and Sub Finalize procedures. For details, see [Object Lifetime: How Objects Are Created and Destroyed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hks5e2k6%28VS.80%29.aspx).

### Data Types

VB.Net introduces three new data types. The Char data type is an unsigned 16-bit quantity used to store Unicode characters. It is equivalent to the .NET Framework System.Char data type. The Short data type, a signed 16-bit integer, was named Integer in earlier versions of Visual Basic. The Decimal data type is a 96-bit signed integer scaled by a variable power of 10. In earlier versions of Visual Basic, it was available only within a Variant. In addition, Visual Basic now supports unsigned integer data types (UShort, UInteger, and ULong), as well as the signed type SByte. For details, see [Data Types in Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ffsdktda%28VS.80%29.aspx).

### Interfaces

Interfaces describe the properties and methods of classes, but unlike classes, interfaces do not provide implementations. Use the Interface statement to declare interfaces; use the Implements statement to write code that puts the items described in the interface into practice. For details, see [Interfaces in Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/28e2e18x.aspx).

### Delegates

Delegates are objects that can call the methods of objects on your behalf and are sometimes described as type-safe, object-oriented function pointers. You can use delegates to let procedures specify an event handler method that runs when an event occurs. You can also use delegates with multithreaded applications. For details, see [Delegates and the AddressOf Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74wy9422%28VS.90%29.aspx).

### Shared Members

Shared members are properties, procedures, and fields that are shared by all instances of a class. Shared data members are useful when multiple objects need to use information that is common to all objects. You can use shared class methods without first creating an object from a class. For details, see [Shared Members in Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4hbsxy95%28VS.80%29.aspx).
References

You can use References to use objects defined in other assemblies. In VB.Net, references point to assemblies instead of type libraries. For details, see [References and the Imports Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9st4tss%28VS.71%29.aspx).

### Namespaces

Namespaces prevent naming conflicts by organizing classes, interfaces, and methods into hierarchies. For details, see [Namespaces in Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt9tafza.aspx).

### Assemblies

Assemblies replace and extend the capabilities of type libraries by describing all the required files for a particular component or application. An assembly can contain one or more namespaces. For details, see [Assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.aspx).

### Attributes

You can use attributes to provide additional information about program elements. For example, you can use an attribute to specify which methods in a class should be exposed when the class is used as a XML Web service. For details, see [Attributes in Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/39967861%28VS.80%29.aspx).

### Multithreading

You can use VB.Net to write applications that can perform multiple tasks independently. A task that can hold up other tasks can execute on a separate thread, a process known as multithreading. By causing complicated tasks to run on threads that are separate from your user interface, multithreading makes your applications more responsive to user input. For details, see [Multithreaded Applications](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/threads/).

### Bit Shift Operators

VB.Net now supports arithmetic left- and right-shift operations on integral data types (Byte, Short, Integer, and Long) as well as on unsigned types (UShort, UInteger, and ULong). Arithmetic shifts are not circular, which means the bits shifted off one end of the result are not reintroduced at the other end. The corresponding assignment operators are provided as well. For details, see [Bit Shift Operators and Assignment Operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw84t893%28VS.71%29.aspx).

### Loop Variable Declaration

You can use VB.Net to declare a loop variable as part of a For or For Each loop. You can include an As clause for the variable in the For or For Each statement, provided no variable of that name has been declared outside the loop. The scope of a loop variable declared in this manner is the loop itself. For details, see [For...Next Statement (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z06z1kb.aspx) and [For Each...Next Statement (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ebk1751.aspx).

Further informations:

- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-SG/Vsexpressvb/thread/15f1ed35-47c4-4ae0-a8a6-16bad23f6947
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172618.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y17w47af.aspx
- http://www.thescarms.com/vbasic/vb6vsvbnet.aspx
- http://www.programmersheaven.com/2/FAQ-VBNET-VB6-VBNET-Differences
- [What's New in the Visual Basic Language for Visual Basic 6.0 Users](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/55yzhfb2.aspx)

**Edit**: as commented some features like constructors were already supported in VB6(in a different way), have a look at the last link what takes that more into account

Comment: +1 for a comprehensive answer and even links to more information!

Comment: All the bullets in first paragraph are plain wrong: 1. in VB6 no one compiled to interpreted EXEs, interpreter is used only in the IDE for debugging. 2. GC is not more efficient than refcounting. 3. VB6 is not interpreter based language -- there is no `eval` function like in JS. 4. VB6 **is** type-safe language, it's just weakly-typed (like C) which is not a "weak" point per se. One thing is for sure -- Microsoft did a great job demonizing VB6, scaring most of the VB6 devs (millions), and later trapping them in .Net. One thing I'm sure too -- this will happen again... with .Net.

Comment: -1. WQW is quite right, and there are other mistakes. VB6 did have interfaces and constructors and destructors.

Comment: @wqw,MarkJ: i have mentioned that in my edit and the last link.

Comment: Marked you up for the great summary.

Comment: Is @wqw correct? Can those mistakes be corrected in the answer?

Answer (score 5):

Classic VB doesn't support most OOP features, while VB.NET does.

Comment: VB.NET has limited support for multiple inheritance (so it doesn't "support all OOP features".  I'm not saying VB classic does, just pointing out your statement is not technically correct.

Comment: I've edited the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 4):

Major differences are Version Number and Object Orientation.

Up to version 6, it was known as VB. From version 7, which was released with .Net 1.0, it was known as VB.NET.

It was completely revamped in version 7 to become more streamlined with .Net Framework (CLI & CLS compatibility) and other languages such as C# and Java.

In this transition, several changes caused broken backward compatibility with previous versions. That is why Microsoft provided a few tools in Visual Studio to convert old VB6 apps into .Net.

- [Visual Basic Reference on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic)
- [Visual Basic .NET Reference on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET)