# VB or VB.NET? How do I know which one to use

Tags: vb.net, vba

I need to make a windows app. Should I use VB or VB.net? What is the real difference actually? I downloaded visual studio for vb and right now I have "microsoft visual basic 2010 express". I'm assuming if I want to use VB.net it'll say "microsoft visual basic.net 2010 express". Where do I get that from though?

Comment: This is the .NET version already. There is no VB 2010 other than .NET.

Comment: There are some differences: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721871/what-is-the-difference-between-vb-and-vb-net/4722445#4722445

Answer (score 2, accepted):

COM-based VB (i.e., "VB6") is obsolete and no longer sold.

VBA is only part of another app or product (such as Excel, Word, etc.) that hosts it and is not appropiate for a stand-alone app.

VB.Net is current, available for purchase (as part of Visual Studio), and supported.

So use VB.Net.

Comment: available for purchase? VB.NET is a programming language which is [free](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET). The IDE to develop using VB.NET is available for purchase but there are Express editions of Visual Studio which allow you to develop for free.

Comment: Appreciate the help guys!

Comment: @mehow That at various times in it's history it has been possible to get it for free is off-point. The point is that, unlike VB6 it is still available as (part of) a product that MS actively sells and markets, which means that they also fix problems and add new features.

Comment: I am really sorry @RBarryYoung but I just disagree with your statement. I think VB.NET is free.

Comment: @mehow It is ***also*** available for purchase.  That's the point.

Comment: VBA is also free and comes with Windows.  VBA is going to be more "system friendly" than vb.net.  Declaring objects at run-time (VBA) keeps you out of the "missing reference" error hole.

Comment: @user652411 No, *VBScript* comes with windows.  VBA only comes within a product or application that hosts it (such as excel).

Comment: True VBScript comes with Windows.  There isn't much difference in VBA and VBScript outside of not being able to assign a type to a variable in VBScript.

Comment: @user652411 No, they are exceptionally different, as different as Javascript and Java.  For one thing VBA is compiled and VBScript is interpreted.  Also, they operate in completely different contexts, and they share no development tools that I know of.  They just have a (somewhat) similar syntax, that's about it.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Basic 2010 Express is the IDE to write VB.NET code. You already have the correct program.

As you're starting now - why not use the newest Visual Studio Express 2012?